# ffmpeg converted vidoe not playing

Tags: video, ffmpeg, html5-video

I am working with ffmpeg php library in these days, I have done every thing video is being converted  and also thumbnail abstracted successfully, But the problem is that html5 is not playing the converted video wheres it is running in windows media player it always says video corrupted. 
Please guide

Here is link for converted video

[Video Link](http://born2invest.com/admin_v3/uploads/news_videos/326e116e766651b728da8eaea3d82587.mp4)

```
$ffmpeg = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg";
$image_name    = rand();
$image_name    = md5($image_name);
$video         = escapeshellarg($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$size          = "200x100";
$imageFile     = "uploads/video_thumbnails/".$image_name.".jpg";
$getFromSecond = "00:0:50";
$p4ath         = "which ffmpeg";
//$cmd         = "$ffmpeg -ss $getFromSecond -i $video -s $size -vframes 1 $imageFile";
$cmd           = "$ffmpeg -i $video -f image2 -ss 14.342 -vframes 1 $imageFile";
$cmd_convert   = "$ffmpeg -i $video uploads/news_videos/$image_name.mp4 &";
//$cmd         = "$ffmpeg -i $video -an -ss $getFromSecond -an -r 1 -vframes 1 -y %d.png";  

exec($cmd);
exec($cmd_convert);
echo $image_name;
```

Html5 video tag

```
  <video width="400" controls>
      <source src="<?php echo $video_image ?>" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
       Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
```

Comment: you are not adding proper coadec info Try this code: ffmpeg -i {input}.mov -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 {output}.mp4

Comment: Thank you manish i have added your code but same error i got :(